# How do I manually fix the registry when Windows incorrectly thinks something is already installed?

Tags: windows-installer

I have had this issue show up about 3 times now where Windows simply thinks my software is installed when it is not. I know the "installed" state is controlled by registry values somewhere, but I have been unable to get Windows to stop thinking the program is installed without rebuilding my msi with a newer version number and installing over the phantom old version (the phantom version does not show up in the add/remove programs).

I am not able to install third-party tools on these machines, so finding the registry keys is my only idea at the moment. Is this my only option? Does anyone know where the keys are stored?

Comment: It would help exactly what error you see and what you're doing when you get it. Are doing a fresh install of something? An upgrade?

Comment: The problem is there is no error! It just doesn't do what it is supposed to do. I use WiX Toolset to install my microservices and the group installer (which chains about 10 msi's together) just passes over the first few msi's in the install chain when I try it via VNC. This would be the default behavior if the same version of that msi is already installed, but nothing is installed yet!

Granted these are customer machines who had a failed install (usually a failed upgrade) which is why I am contacted, so I have no idea what they have done to their machines before I get to them.

Comment: Verbose installer logs should detail exactly why each chained MSI is skipped. Do you have them?

Comment: I am not sure. The group installer (compiled via Wix's Heat) does leave a pretty hefty log behind. Let me go poke around at that and see if I can find something.

Answer (score 0):

Look in:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer]

Also see:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Installer]

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin Richardson says, get the verbose logs for the installs that don't do anything. Yes, the products may already be installed, but why look at hacking the registry? The installed state might be "controlled by registry entries" but there are registry entries not only for the product but also for its UpgradeCode and every component in the MSI file. The idea that you can clean things up by messing around with some of this is a non-starter, sorry. You should know the ProductCode values for those MSIs, so ask the customer to do an msiexec /x {ProductCode guid} and see what happens. That should be the first step. If you've done that and it didn't work, then that's useful data and again a verbose log might help.

You don't need to install 3rd party tools - see if they will run this VBScript. It will enumerate all the installed products on the system, and detect if yours is there - it will list the details into a text file:

```
Option Explicit
Public installer, fullmsg, comp, prod, a, fso, pname, ploc, pid, psorce, pcache, pver

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fso.CreateTextFile("prods.txt", True)

' Connect to Windows Installer object
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
a.writeline ("Products")
on error resume next
For Each prod In installer.products
   pid = installer.productinfo (prod, "ProductID")
   pname = installer.productinfo (prod, "ProductName")
   pver = installer.productinfo (prod, "VersionString")
   psorce=installer.productinfo(prod, "InstallSource")
   ploc = installer.productinfo (prod, "InstallLocation")  
 pcache = installer.productinfo(prod, "LocalPackage") 
   a.writeline (prod & " " & pname & " Version " & pver & " installed at " & ploc & " from " & psorce & " cached at " & pcache)
Next
```

Anyway, get those logs!